# How to send additional parameters in @Ajax.Beginform() along with model values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajaxform

I'm using @Ajax.BeginForm() in my asp.net mvc3 application.
Since the page is tightly bound, it sends the model values on click of the submit button.
My requirement is that onclick of submit button, I need to populate a listbox that is present outside the form using some logic and pass the Json list of values present in the listbox to the controller as an additional parameter.
How to achieve this?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Controller_Method", "Controller_Name", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "SUCCESS" }))
{
}

<select id="listbx">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Onclick of submit button, I add item to the listbox using jQuery and want to pass all the items as a json parameter to the controller..

Answer (score 1):

You could [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the selectbox inside the form in a hidden div before submitting the form.

Also don't forget to add a `name` attribute to the select list or nothing will get posted to the controller:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Controller_Method", "Controller_Name", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "SUCCESS", OnBegin = "beforeSend" }))
{
    <div id="listBoxContainer" style="display:none;"></div>
}

<select id="listbx" name="listbox">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and then implement the `beforeSend` callback to clone the selectbox into the form:

```
function beforeSend() {
    $('#listBoxContainer').html($('#listbx').clone());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I accept the value in the controller? Should I add a parameter? Because I cannot associate a Model parameter to it. I don't mind if I am able to send the entire #listbx list as a json array as a parameter. How to do it?

Comment: You would have a parameter with the same `name` as your dropdown (`listbox` in my example).

Comment: I did exactly as you said. But still model parameter is returned to  controller is null. Can you show the controller code?

Comment: Here's the controller action signature: `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Controller_Method(string listbox) { ... }`. List of things to check: your javascript console for errors; the network tab in your javascript debugging tool to see exactly what gets sent to the server - if you cannot see the `listbox` value in the request payload you probably forgot to add a name to it.